# tkinter - Change color of a disabled entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

Is there a way that I could change a color of disabled entry widget in python?

```
x = tk.Entry(parent)
x.configure({"background": "gray24"})
x.configure({"fg": "white"})
x.configure({"state": "disable"})
```

The code above only works when the "state" of the widget is "normal".

Answer (score 5):

Set the entry widget's `disabledbackground` attribute.

```
x.configure({"disabledbackground": "newcolour"})
```

Where `"newcolour"` is the colour you want to see when the entry widget is disabled. You can also use `disabledforeground` for foreground colours, rather than background colours.