# How to change state of tkinter entry without changing other variables of the entry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am working on a sudoku generation application and I want to set all given entry cells to read only but If I change these entries to the readonly state it resets the background color.

```
entries.append(tk.Entry(master, width=5, background='grey'))

entries[i].configure(state='readonly')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter-change-color-of-a-disabled-entry-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58966640)

Comment: If you read the documentation you'll see that there is a `disabledbackground` and `disabledforeground` option.